# Cumulocity real-time latest measurement fetching

Tags: cumulocity

```
c8yMeasurements.latest(filter, realtime)
  .then(function (latestMeasurement) {
    vm.text = latestMeasurement.c8y_TemperatureMeasurement.T.value;
    console.log(vm.text);
  });
```

I tried to fetch the latest measurement from a certain device using the document here: http://resources.cumulocity.com/documentation/jssdk/latest/#/api/c8y.core.service:c8yMeasurements.

However, I'm not quite sure how the `realtime` thing actually works. I set `realtime` to true, but the value of `vm.text` was not updated every time the agent change value.

To work around with it, I used `setInterval` method in JS (which is quite nasty T T). And then it works fine in my customised application.

However, after I `c8y build:plugin hello` (`hello` is the name of my plugin) and uploaded the zip file to cockpit, the value cannot fetched.

Please help :( Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In order to make it work in realtime you need to wrap the result into a function so angular can call it when updating the model. Here an example

```
function getLatestMeasurementForDatapoint({ fragment, series, __target }) {
  return c8yMeasurements.latest({
      fragment,
      series,
      device: _.get(__target, 'id')
    }, true)
      .then(
        (rtLatestMeasurement) => {
          return {
            value: () => _.get(rtLatestMeasurement, [fragment, series, 'value'])
          };
        }
      );
}
```

In your controller you can then call this function which will return an object containing the key value

```
getLatestMeasurementForDatapoint(vm.datapoint)
  .then((latestMeasurement) => { vm.latestMeasurement = latestMeasurement; });
```

Finally in you model you can then refer to that result. Note that value is a function so you need to call it like a function.

```
{{vm.latestMeasurement.value()}}
```